# Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http

Tags: flutter, dart

I am running an application in a flutter, unfortunately, I got the same error, again and again, saying - ***Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:-----/-------/***

For the past 2 days, I'm struggling to get the fix but got no solution for this. I have updated my flutter and dart already. I have run the *flutter doctor* but found no issues in that. For more info, you can refer to the below screenshot!

> Flutter Doctor logs.

```
PS D:\FlutterProjects_VSCode\New folder\flutter_application_1> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1902], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.6 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 1d9032c7e1 (3 days ago), 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 05e680e202
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 51.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.21.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • HTC Desire 526GPLUS dual sim (mobile) • HQ53AYL09915 • android-arm    • Android 4.4.2 (API 19)
    • Chrome (web)                          • chrome       • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.93
    • Edge (web)                            • edge         • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 90.0.818.51

• No issues found!
```

> The Error I have got[Please refer to the below picture]:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on HTC Desire 526GPLUS dual sim in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/DartVM  (25735): vm-service: Error: Unhandled exception:
E/DartVM  (25735): Unimplemented handling of missing static target
E/DartVM  (25735): #0      new _HttpConnection.<anonymous closure> (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2728:25)
E/DartVM  (25735): #1      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1546:10)
E/DartVM  (25735): #2      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
E/DartVM  (25735): #3      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/DartVM  (25735): #4      _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:733:19)
E/DartVM  (25735): #5      _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:607:7)
E/DartVM  (25735): #6      _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:554:5)
E/DartVM  (25735): #7      _HttpParser._headersEnd (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:387:19)
E/DartVM  (25735): #8      _HttpParser._doParse (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:745:15)
E/DartVM  (25735): #9      _HttpParser._parse (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:324:7)
E/DartVM  (25735): #10     _HttpParser._onData (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:858:5)
E/DartVM  (25735): #11     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1546:10)
E/DartVM  (25735): #12     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/st
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:***/********=/
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the actual code, not an image

Comment: Replaced images with code! Thank you!

Comment: are you running it in emulator or another device?? if is another device, don't use a localhost ip

Comment: I tried on both devices - on the emulator and on my real device. But still got the same error.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69730208/9942927. It worked for me.